# Keep text inside HTML in rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to know how can I keep only the text between <> after running rvest on a specific attribute and website URL. This is the character set I get on the output

```
{xml_nodeset (11)}
 [1] <td id="open">1.1041</td>
 [2] <td id="open">1.1043</td>
 [3] <td id="open">1.1049</td>
 [4] <td id="open">1.1043</td>
 [5] <td class="right" id="open">47.617</td>
 [6] <td class="left" id="open">MA</td>
```

Ideally I want to isolate the contained text and get this

```
[1] 1.1041
[2] 1.1043
[3] 1.1049
[4] 1.1043
[5] 47.617
[6] MA
```

but so far by using the html_text function I get a concatenated string with "" between values which is not what I want

```
[1] "1.1041" "1.1043" "1.1049" "1.1043" "47.617" "MA"
```

Comment: That's not one string, it's six. Their print method puts quotes on them to tell you they are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is being coerced to string format because of the last value `MA`. That's why you get quotes around the numbers.

You can convert everything to numeric, but the last value would be coerced to `NA`.

```
q <- c("1.1041", "1.1043", "1.1049", "1.1043", "47.617", "MA")
as.numeric(q)

# The output of the previous command is:
[1]  1.1041  1.1043  1.1049  1.1043 47.6170      NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

So you have to decide what format you want your data in.